# How do I write a string to the next line in a file?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, file-writing

I am trying to make a Tkinter program that writes a line to a file then displays it below in a label. I have worked out how to display a line of the file in labels but when I use the writing feature it writes the new line over the top of the old line not on the next line. Please tell me how to write to the next line.
Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
f=open("stats")
line1=f.readline()
line2=f.readline()
line3=f.readline()
line4=f.readline()
line5=f.readline()
line6=f.readline()
line7=f.readline()
line8=f.readline()
line9=f.readline()
line10=f.readline()

def write():
      f=open("stats", "w")
      f.write(e1.get())
      f.write(" ")
      f.write(e2.get())
      f.write("\n")
      e1.delete(0, END)
      e2.delete(0, END)

root=Tk()
root.title("Basketball Stats")
l1=Label(text="Player").grid(column=0, row=0)
l2=Label(text="Number").grid(column=0, row=1)
e1=Entry().grid(column=1, row=0)
e2=Entry().grid(column=1, row=1)
b1=Button().grid(column=1, row=3)
b1.config(text="Submit", command=write)
l3=Label(text=line1).grid(column=0, row=4)
l4=Label(text=line2).grid(column=0, row=5)
l5=Label(text=line3).grid(column=0, row=6)
l6=Label(text=line4).grid(column=0, row=7)
l7=Label(text=line5).grid(column=0, row=8)
l8=Label(text=line6).grid(column=0, row=9)
l9=Label(text=line7).grid(column=0, row=10)
l10=Label(text=line8).grid(column=0, row=11)
l11=Label(text=line9).grid(column=0, row=12)
l12=Label(text=line10).grid(column=0, row=13)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you re-open the file every time you write a line.
Move the open command to the main program -- and remember to close it when you're done.

Comment: good answer ... probably even better than my suggestion to open the file in append mode  :P

Comment: please suggest an edit to illustrate what you mean… i can't get it to work

Comment: Move the "open" command to be the first line of your main program.  If that gives you a scoping problem within "write", then pass the file descriptor (f) as an argument to "write".

If you still have trouble, please post the code you used and the error message(s) you got.  "can't get it to work" is too general.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
def write():
   f=open("stats", "a")
```

"w" creates a new file deleteing any existing file

"a" appends to an existing file, or creates it if it does not exist